# What should nodejs NOT be doing?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm now a couple of weeks into my node deep dive. I've learned a lot from Anthony's excellent course on udemy and I'm currently going through a book " nodejs the right way". I've also gone through quite a few articles that brought up some very good points about real world scenarios with node and coupling other technologies out there.

HOWEVER, it seems to be accepted as law, that you don't perform computationally heavy tasks with Node as its a single thread architecture. I get the idea of the event loop and asynch callbacks etc. In fact nodes strength stems from tons of concurrent IO connections if I understand correctly. No matter where I'm reading though, the source warns against hanging up that thread executing a task. I can't seem to find any rule of thumb of things to avoid using nodes process for. I've seen a solution saying that node should pass computationally heavy tasks to a message service like RabbitMQ which a dedicated app server can churn through(any suggestions on what pairs well with node for this task? I read something about an N-tier architecture). The reason  I'm so confused is because I see node being used for reading and writing files to highlight the usage of streams but in my mind fetching/reading/writing files is an expensive task (I feel mistaken).

Tl;Dr What kind of tasks should node pass off to a work horse server ? What material can I read that explains the paradigm in detail?

Edit: it seems like my lack of understanding stemmed from not knowing what would even halt a thread in the first place outside of an obviously synchronous IO request . So if I understand correctly reading and writing data is IO where mutating said data or doing mathematical computations is computationally expensive  (at varying levels depending on the task of course ) . Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: Why the elixir - tag?  Yes Elixir/Phoenix is the alternative to nodejs web server.

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff because when I was researching I saw several mentions of offloading certain tasks to a messaging service that a server written with erlang (Elixir?) Would handle best. Although after reading responses I no longer feel consequently obligated to learn that.

Comment: I am removing the Elixir tag because your question has nothing to do with Elixir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using node.js as a server, then running a long running synchronous computational task ties up the one thread and during that computation, your server is non-responsive to other requests.  That's generally a bad situation for servers.

So, the general design principles for node.js server design is this:

1. Use only asynchronous I/O functions.  For example, use `fs.readFile()`, not `fs.readyFileSync()`.
2. If you have a computationally intense operation, then move it to a child process.  If you do a lot of these, then have several child processes that can process these long running operations.  This keeps your main thread free so it can be responsive to I/O requests.
3. If you want to increase the overall scalability and responsiveness of your server, you can implement clustering with a server process per CPU.  This isn't really a substitute for #2 above, but can also improve scalability and responsiveness.

> The reason I'm so confused is because I see node being used for
>   reading and writing files to highlight the usage of streams but in my
>   mind fetching/reading/writing files is an expensive task (I feel
>   mistaken).

If you use the asynchronous versions of the I/O functions, then read/writing from the disk does not block the main JS thread as they present an asynchronous interface and the main thread can do other things while the system is fetching data from the disk.

> What kind of tasks should node pass off to a work horse server ?

It depends a bit on the server load that you are trying to support, what you're asking it to do and your tolerance for responsiveness delays.  The higher the load you're aiming for, then the more you need to get any computationally intensive task off the main JS thread and into some other process.  At a medium number of long running transactions and a modest server load, you may just be able to use clustering to reach your scalability and responsiveness goal, but at some threshold of either length of the transaction or the load you're trying to support, you have to get the computationally intensive stuff out of the main JS thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot I understand now! Spawning another thread to parse or compute in some cases is beneficial if that task is going to take a long time to process. This is because the interpreter is only running one line of code at once and if it gets stuck on a line parsing a huge file or stream it can halt the process. So off putting that task to a separate thread would be to my benefit , right? (I'm not sure how to go about that at all yet but I know what to look for now, thanks again)

Answer (score 1):

> HOWEVER, it seems to be accepted as law, that you don't perform computationally heavy tasks with Node as its a single thread architecture.

I would reword this:

> don't perform computationally heavy tasks **unless you need to** with Node

Sometimes, you need to crunch through a bunch of data.  There are times when it's faster or better to do that in-process than it is to pass it around.

### A practical example:

I have a Node.js server that reads in raw log data from a bunch of servers.  No standard logging utilities could be used as I have some custom processing being done, as well as custom authentication schemes for getting the log data.  The whole thing is HTTP requests, and then parsing and re-writing the data.

As you can imagine, this uses a ton of CPU.  Here's the thing though... is that CPU wasted?  Am I doing anything in JS that I could do faster had I written it in another language?  Often times the CPU is busy for a real reason, and the benefit of switching to something more native might be marginal.  And then, you have to factor in the overhead of switching.

Remember that with Node.js, you can compile native extensions, so it's possible to have the best of both worlds in a well established framework.

For me, the human trade-offs came in.  I'm a far more efficient Node.js developer than anything that runs natively.  Even if my Node.js app were prove to be 5x slower than something native (which I'd imagine would be on the extreme), I could just buy 5 more servers to run, at much less cost than it would take for me to develop and maintain the native solution.

Use what you need.  If you need to burn a lot of CPU in Node.js, just make sure you're doing it as efficiently as you can be.  If you find that you could optimize something with native code, consider making an extension and besure to measure the performance differences afterwards.  If you feel the desire to throw out the whole stack... reconsider your approach, as there *might* be something you're not considering.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wish I could up vote but I'm not allowed to yet. The practical example really brought it home for me. I didn't know what would be considered CPU intensive until you gave that example. Now I have an idea of what kind of operations might block the main thread by resource hogging.

Comment: @JacariJones Basically, anything that happens in your JavaScript is going to be on a single thread... so data manipulation usually.  Anything that's I/O related will be handled by the thread pool.  Anything in native extensions can do whatever its wants.  One other note to mention that when you are distributing your load across multiple hosts, it's actually desirable to load them up as much as you can.  Not because you want to create load, but because you want to use whatever capacity you have before scaling to more hosts.  You're paying for 100% of the CPU, might as well use it.

Comment: @JacariJones In practice, 100% utilization isn't possible.  You'll always be blocked by something.  Usually I/O is the blocker which is why the normal single-main-thread approach of writing a Node.js app isn't bad.  I can cause a 24-core server to use all of its available CPU without any attempt on my part of multithreading.  This of course depends on the nature of your program.

Comment: @JacariJones One final note... if at all possible, let a regular web server handle the web serving.  A lot of people use Node.js as a web server which is acceptable for smaller installations, but if you have static files, let Nginx or similar handle it.  Let Nginx proxy to your Node.js instance so that Nginx handles all the transport compression, spoon-feeding of clients, etc.  Nginx is much better at this than the stock HTTP server components in Node.js. The HTTP methods exist in Node primarily as a protocol for getting data to servers, not meant to be used directly in high load environments.

Comment: More to your point of causing a 24-core server to use all of it's available cpu (would it be more specific to say the capacity of each of it's cores,right?), you can require 'os', count the cores and spawn a child process for each core. Each one of these cores(and their respective processes) are part of a node cluster that the master js thread can pass off certain tasks to right ? (I need to learn more about this, or rather where ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ come into play as opposed to the included IPC ) I think I can see a hazy silhouette of the bigger picture. I appreciate it!

Comment: Sure you can do that, but my point is that you often don't have to. It's very often an overused technique due to a misunderstanding of Node.js. Run your app, see how the load is, profile, and adjust from there.

Comment: overthinking has been my pitfall more often than not. - don't waste energy or resources trying to over engineer. "Use what you need" and add more IF I need it and try to do it without increasing overhead through complexity if possible

Answer (score 0):

Reading and writing files are I/O operations, so they are NOT CPU intensive.  You can do a fair amount of concurrent I/O with Node without tying up any single request (in a Node HTTP server for example).

But people use Node in general for CPU-intensive tasks all the time and its fine.  You just have to realize that if it uses all of the CPU for any significant amount of time then you will block all other requests to that server, which generally won't be acceptable if you need the server to stay available.  But there are lots of times when your Node process is not trying to be a server firing back responses to many requests, such as when you have a Node program that just processes data and isn't a server at all.

Also, using another process is not the only way to do background tasks in Node.  There is also `webworker-threads` which allows you to use threads if that is more convenient (you do have to copy the data in and out).

I would stop reading and do some targeted experiments so you can see what they are talking about.  Try to create and test three different programs: 1) HTTP server handles lots of requests, always returns immediately with file contents 2) HTTP server handles lots of requests, but a certain request causes a large math computation that takes many seconds to return (which will block all the other requests -- big problem) 3) a Node program that is not an HTTP server, which does that large math computation and spits out the result in the terminal (which even though it takes awhile to work, is not handling other requests since its not a server, so its fine for it to block).

Comment: Thanks ! I'll take your advice and start playing around with different implementations and see if I can intentionally push them to their limits. And then figure out the best way to solve the problem.